# React component import not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am trying to use this gem:

http://kyleamathews.github.io/react-component-gallery/

So I installed it using `npm`

```
npm install react-component-gallery
```

And I created a React component like this:

```
var Gallery = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (

  <ComponentGallery
    className="example"
    margin=10
    noMarginBottomOnLastRow=true
    widthHeightRatio=3/5
    targetWidth=250>
      <img src="https://example.com/pic1.jpg" />
      <img src="https://example.com/pic2.jpg" />
      <img src="https://example.com/pic3.jpg" />
      <img src="https://example.com/pic4.jpg" />
      <img src="https://example.com/pic5.jpg" />
      <img src="https://example.com/pic6.jpg" />
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/relaterocket-logos/nike.com-black@2x.png" />
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/relaterocket-logos/gopro.com-black@2x.png" />
    </ComponentGallery>
    );
  }

});
```

However I am getting this error:

```
JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX t
ext (10:11)
```

Where line 10 is this:

```
margin=10
```

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX is XML-like.  Your attribute values need to be quoted strings, expressions, or other JSX elements.  In your case, e.g.

```
margin="10"
noMarginBottomOnLastRow={true}
```

(The second could be `"true"`, just giving an example of an expression.)